# Financial Cloud and Approval Process

Tags: financialforce

I'm looking for information about approval process on financial cloud, but I did not found clear information. Someone knows if is possible to set approval process on financial cloud?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of broad, but the short answer is that yes it should be possible to set approval processes on objects in FinancialForce. FinancialForce uses the same platform as the rest of Salesforce, just with some custom code on top.

The problem may be that you want to initiate approvals from a Visualforce page. You won't have any control over package Visualforce pages, so you can't add the submit for approval button.